# AWS Route 53 - How to create private sub domains under public hosted zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a public dns(hosted zone) in route 53 company.com and I created a public sub-domain(another public hosted zone) sales.company.com.
Till this point everything is working fine and i am able to access my application through sales.company.com successfully.

Now I created another private sub-domain insights.sales (i.e. private hosted zone insights.sales.company.com ), I added name servers associated with this
private sub-domain in company.com hosted zone, what I want is, insights.sales.company.com should be resolved only within my company network.

But I am not able to reach insights.sales.company.com.
My understanding is first it will resolve company.com which is public and then it will forward to name servers associated with insights.sales.

Can anyone please help me on how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Private hosted zones are only for DNS resolution within VPCs. You would not add a private hosted zone's name servers to the public zone. Instead you would attach the private hosted zone to one or more VPCs.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, but I don't want to use private hosted zones. What I want to do is add an NS record to my primary zone (e.g. sub.example.com) that points to e.g. ns.example.com, which has an A record in the primary zone that resolves to an internal IP. Where I am getting stuck is in the recursive lookup--dig finds the NS record but because Amazon's servers can't route to the internal IP I get an NXDOMAIN response. Is there any way to force iterative lookups on a subdomain rather than recursive from Route53's standpoint?

Comment: @m-bers Please post that as a separate question on this site instead of tacking onto the comments in this question.